# Camera doesn't work on android 2.2

Tags: android, camera, android-2.2-froyo

In Android SDK and AVD Manager, I created a new android virtual device as following:

- Name: myavd
- Target: Android 2.2 - API Level 8.
- SD Card: 50MiB.
- Build-in: Default (HVGA).
- Hardware: Abstracted LCD density 160.

After starting this device, I can't take a picture from build-in camera. The following is the error and exception.

*The application Camera (process com.android.camera) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.*

> 08-18 15:00:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 11
>   08-18 15:00:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
>   08-18 15:00:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:760)
>   08-18 15:00:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:916)
>   08-18 15:00:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1246)
>   08-18 15:00:47.940: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
>   08-18 15:00:48.369: WARN/ActivityManager(66):   Force finishing activity com.android.camera/.Camera

Do you know what is wrong ?

Comment: emulator 2.2 is broken. Please vote for this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9376
 so we can get a fix

Answer (score 6):

It seems that this is normal behaviour. check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).
The emulator does not seem to support camera. Here are these limitations :

Emulator Limitations

In this release, the limitations of the emulator include:

```
* No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator console, however.
* No support for USB connections
* No support for camera/video capture (input).
* No support for device-attached headphones
* No support for determining connected state
* No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging state
* No support for determining SD card insert/eject
* No support for Bluetooth
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it has worked on Android 2.1 and lower, don't know why the issue happens on android 2.2 :(

Comment: That is weird indeed, I do have the same issue. I'll make some research and post back here if I find something interesting

Comment: In emulator 1.6 the default Android image was returned from the built in Camera activity, which was fine for various testing. In emulator 2.2 you get an exception instead. I consider this a bug in the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong: emulator 2.2 is broken.

Workaround: Create an AVD with 2.1 as the target.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer here. [Camera crashes in Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935193/camera-crashes-in-android-2-2). You might not be detecting the available preview sizes correctly.