# Camera crashes in Android 2.2

Tags: android, camera, android-2.2-froyo

I have tested my application on the Android SDK on everything from 1.5 to 2.2 and the camera code in my activity works fine. Running it on a device with 2.1 is also working. But the same app does not work with 2.2 on HTC Desire and Nexus One and the app crashes. Any ideas why they might be happening?

Am using **import android.hardware.Camera;**.

Inside onCreate I have this:

```
preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
        previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

And the callback is

```
SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in setPreviewDisplay", t);
            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, t.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }
};
```

Comment: Generally, most SO questions involving an Android crash will end up getting ignored unless you include a copy-paste of the error trace from Logcat. It's easy to do and often helps other devs identify the problem very quickly.

Comment: It's not crashing on my SDK and Android 2.1 I have. So don't see any errors in the logcat (I tried it in the SDK and it worked). Crashing on a friend's phone who is a few hundred kms away. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Need to set the preview size of the camera after getting the optimal camera sizes. Here are the details and the code for the fix-

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7909

Comment: -1, Please Post answer here because no one is going to read your long list of conversation.

Comment: It's not my long list of conversation. It's a pretty comprehensive bug report with different screenshots and different solutions for different devices which can not possibly fit into one answer. Please do not dispense downvotes without knowing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the width and height passed by the surfaceChanged method is not a preview size supported.

So if you wanna set the preview size (parameters.setPreviewSize), you need to set a supported preview size. The method getPreviewSize() returns an available preview size. So your surfaceChanged method can be like that:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    Size pSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    Log.d(TAG, "Setting preview size: " + pSize.width + " x " + pSize.height);

    parameters.setPreviewSize(pSize.width, pSize.height);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

You can also get a list of the supported preview sizes using the method [getSupportedPreviewSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29) available from android api version 5.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take photo from camera then you have to crop.and then save or set.

You can used this code.

```
                Intent intent   = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                  
                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"connectR_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);                       
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

OnActivityResult.

```
case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            doCrop();               
            break;
```

now croping the image used **doCrop()**

```
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();      
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");        
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );        
    int size = list.size();        
    if (size == 0) {            
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);            
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);              
            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));                
            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();                 
                co.title    = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon     = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);                   
                co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                    startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                }
            });

            builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            } );

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }
```