# camera issue in emulator 2.2 in android

Tags: android

i am suffering with a problem that in android 2.2 emulator, camera doesn't work. it closes down the camera automatically. But this problem is not happening in android 1.5 emulator.
Why it is happening? can any body help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue and has been asked several times on SO - here are some pointers to possible solutions. However, the camera emulation in 2.2 is known to be buggy:

- [Removing the stencil buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948809/emulators-camera-built-in-app-buggy-in-froyo-2-2)
- [Switching to 2.1 or 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510164/camera-doesnt-work-on-android-2-2)

So you have two options: Either you try to follow the directions, given by the correct answer in the first thread or switch to an emulator running on either 2.1 or 2.3+.