# Camera at Android 2.1 works fine but doesn't in Android 2.2. Why?

Tags: android-camera, android-sdk-2.1, android-2.2-froyo

I have to develop an android app for which I have to use camera feature. Before developing the app I checked the default camera app of emulator and I found that it works in Android 2.1 but doesn't works in Android 2.2. Can anybody say why this happens? Is this the problem of some configuration while creating the AVD or some other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.
There is nothing like camera feature at android 2.1 works fine but in android 2.2, it doesn't works fine. because after a long struggle I solved the problem just by releasing the camera properly and implement the code inside onSurfaceChanged method of the Preview class.

So now it works fine in all Android 2.1, 2.2 and also in 2.3

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue and discussed many times. You can look some of the posts.

In this release Android 2.2, there are some limitations of the emulator. "**No support for camera/video capture (input).**" is also one of them.

You can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734430/camera-problem-in-emulator-2-2-in-android) for more details.

Comment: I have given you a link of the post where he has explained some solutions. But according to me the best way is to test camera app on device.

Comment: sorry for my undoing my acceptance on your answer. Because camera also works in Android 2.2